# Why number of definitions decrease in Avast 9 when virus definitions is updated?

Tags: anti-virus, avast

I use Avast 9 in my HP notebook and am a great fan of Avast. I prefer to use it in all the systems that I use. Before Avast I was using Avast 8. Its number of definitions was above 50,00,000. With each definitions update the number of definitions kept increasing.

But in Avast 9, things are different. Its number of definitions is below 25,00,000. With each definitions update its number of definitions is decreasing most of the time. So I have 2 doubts.

- Why the number of definitions is half in Avast 9 than that of Avast 8 ?
- Why the number of definitions decreases most of the time(which was increasing in Avast 8) when a definitions update is made in Avast 9 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **Avast blog** there is an [`article`](http://blog.avast.com/2010/09/06/spring-cleaning-in-our-virus-database/) that talks about this.

> Now it is time to clean up and reduce the number of unnecessary
>   detections. The main reason for this is to decrease the size of our
>   virus database updates sent to users around the globe. This will
>   reduce the amount of transferred data, subsequently reducing the
>   amount of needed energy and helping, of course, our forests.....